# How to get multiple values from a react select component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

```
return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="form-group">
        <select name="sub"     onChange={(e) => {
        const selectedPackage = e.target.value;
      
        setPackage(selectedPackage)
       }>
       


  <option   value="0">* Select Subscription Package</option>
          {subPackages.status ?  subPackages.data.map(spack => (
        <option    key={spack.id}   value={spack.id}
         >{spack.title}</option> )) : <Fragment>
            <p>loading</p>
            </Fragment>}
            </select >
            </div>
            { user.uid!=null ?
            <Fragment>
            <Subscription subData = {subData}/></Fragment>   
            : <Fragment> <p>loading</p> </Fragment>
            }
      </Fragment>
    )
}
```

I mapped through an array and displayed the subscription packages on a select option. now I need to fetch the package id and the price from this option. i am only able to get the id from the value attribute of the option. how do I fetch the price?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the price based on the id you provided and the data.
In your case something like this:

`const selectedPackage = subPackages.data.find(elem => elem.id === e.target.value)`

Comment: i still don't understan, help help explain better.

Comment: i have the value of each option already. i just don't know how to fetch  the price.

Comment: oh, i get it. Thank you so much